# Present Git commit ID/SHA in a spring-boot application using gradle?

Tags: java, git, spring-boot

Based on this guide:

https://blog.mrhaki.com/2016/12/spring-sweets-add-git-info-to-info.html

I am trying to implement an endpoint that prints git information (SHA, branch, author, etc.). The above guide mentions that you get this endpoint: `/info` when using:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html

But since I would like to keep my example as simple as possible I was wondering if it was possible to get something similar but *without* using the actuator project but still use:

https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties

I have this in my **build.gradle** file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties" version "2.3.1"    
}

group = projectGroup
version = projectVersion
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And my Spring boot application:

```
package helloworld;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

With this custom `/info` controller/endpoint:

```
package helloworld;

import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

@RestController
public class InfoController {

    @GetMapping("/info")
    public ResponseEntity<String> info() throws IOException {

        File resource = new ClassPathResource("git.properties").getFile();
        String gitInfo = new String(Files.readAllBytes(resource.toPath()));

        return ResponseEntity.ok(gitInfo);
    }
}
```

And it gets the job done. But was wondering if I could do better/more spring-boot standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.info.git-commit-information):

> A GitProperties bean is auto-configured if a git.properties file is available at the root of the classpath. See "Generate git information" for more details.

It follows explaining what is exposed.

If you need extra properties, you could do in gradle:

```
gitProperties {
    extProperty = 'gitProps' // git properties will be put in a map at project.ext.gitProps
    customProperty 'git.build.version', { project.parent.version }
    dotGitDirectory = "${project.rootDir}"
}
```

I also add them in manifest usually:

```
bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'com.App'
    archiveFileName = 'app.jar'
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Build-Revision': "${-> project.ext.gitProps['git.commit.id.abbrev']}"  // Use GString lazy evaluation to delay until git properties are populated
        )
    }
 }
```

I once [wrote a plugin](https://github.com/wind57/0x-plugin-bom) that will auto-configure some of the things, including this functionality.

Comment: Yes the git info file is generated as expected and I can also load/present it in the controller as show in my example. My question was more if there was a better way to do that when NOT using Actuator

Comment: @u123 internally Spring will read the file the same way you do it here, just that they will also have multiple abstractions also. But the main idea would be the same. I don't think there is a "better" way.